# How to pass generic type of array as the parameter for the function in Golang

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang, My question is how to make function accept generic type of parameter. Here is the specific problem I met recently:

I defined a struct which contains a function

```
type TestArgs struct {
    name string
    ...
    customAssertForTypeA func(array []*pb.TypeA)
    customAssertForTypeB func(array []*pb.TypeB)
}

// Define the test case with TestArgs.
tests := []TestArgs{
        {
            name: "Test A",
            customAssertForTypeA: func(array []*pb.TypeA) {
                // Some code
            }
        },
        {
            name: "Test B",
            customAssertForTypeB: func(array []*pb.TypeB) {
                // Some code
            }
        },
}
```

My question is how to make customerAssert function accept generic type of parameter?
I saw some similar question with solution `interface{}`, so I tried

```
customAssert func(array interface{})
```

and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Type assertions** ( https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 )  is what you need when you have an `interface{}` and want to access to the concrete value:

```
type TestArgs struct {
    name         string
    customAssert func(interface{})
}

// Define the test case with TestArgs.
tests := []TestArgs{
    {
        name: "Test A",
        customAssert: func(param interface{}) {
            // Some code
            array, ok := param.([]*pb.TypeA)
            if !ok {
                t.Fatal("assertion error TypeA")
            }
            // use array
        },
    },
    {
        name: "Test B",
        customAssert: func(param interface{}) {
            // Some code
            array, ok := param.([]*pb.TypeB)
            if !ok {
                t.Fatal("assertion error TypeB")
            }
            // use array
        },
    },
}
```